# Turn server is requirement for clients which behind of firewall

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I developed p2p webrtc application which users can video call from web application to mobile application. Web application will run on kiosk and kiosks will be behind firewall. Is it required turn server and all of data relayed by turn server?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where your application is hosted at, what matters is if the clients on the ends of their calls are behind firewalls or other restrictions that restrict p2p and WebRTC, in that case, the data will have to be relayed through TURN servers.

So, no, not all data will be relayed through TURN servers, it depends on the clients' internet environment, but generally TURN servers are a requirement for production applications since there will be a significant amount of situations (about 20% to 30% in average, based on my own experience) where a TURN server is needed for WebRTC to connect.

Answer (score 0):

All kiosks will be behind the firewall, so all traffic goes through turn server means high hardware costs. All of the calls will be from kiosks.10-20% of the traffic to pass through, but not 100% of the cost will increase a lot